# Choosing the right tool for html5 game development

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

I want to develop a poker - like html5 game (for mobile use). I am confused by the variety of frameworks and tools on the market. The game will have a poker table with basic animations and some popups and dropdown list for the user to choose from. The backend will be asp.net using sever sent events to push data in real time to the clients.
I started with jquery mobile /sencha touch but I that they are not the right tools for this propose. Then I saw [impactjs](http://impactjs.com/) that seems better. Can you please focus me to the right tools for my propose? Would impactjs will be good for me?

Another question: what is better for my propose: canvas or svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like for propose with basic animations and some pop-ups so will be with HTML5, CSS3 and javascript. If someone more complex or pretty so impactjs.

Sencha will help you by someone effects like this 'slide', 'fade' or 'pop' there are very beautiful for sencha app.

I hope this helps. :) Ciao.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a similar game using impactjs and smartfoxserver. Works pretty well!. Although only Internet Explorer 10 is supported by Smartfox, besides the others.